# missing argument?

Tags: php

I am getting a MySQL invalid Query error in my scripts.
It doesn't list the line the error occurs on so I am not sure if it is a SQL syntax error or if it can't find the connection.
To try and catch the error I made an error function.
However, even that errors with a missing arg:
Warning: Missing argument 1 for senderroremail(), calle

```
function senderroremail($line) {
    mail('xxx@xxx.co.uk', 'IntegrityCheck script error', mysql_error().' error');
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error().' '.$line );  
}

if (!$squid_conn_int)     {senderroremail(__LINE__);}
```

I have the senderroremail after every query, insert, update, etc.

Comment: The mysql-extensions is not maintained for a long time now and will be flagged as deprecated with 5.5. Use PDO_MySQL or MySQLi. php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: but that's separate from the function above?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that error saying that **_*LINE*_** isn't returning a value?

What does print(**_*LINE*_**); get you?
Have you tried something like senderroremail(777); ?